# Retornar mongodb collections em json_encode PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

estou montando um REST API em PHP e não estou conseguindo exibir todas as collections retornada da busca do mongo, retorna apenas uma. Segue o código para quem puder dar uma contribuição ficarei muito grato. =]!

```
private function slcTwitter($since, $until){

    // Configuration
    $dbhost = 'localhost:27017';
    $dbname = 'twitter';

    // Connect to twitter database
    $m = new Mongo("mongodb://$dbhost");
    $db = $m->$dbname;

    // Get the users collection
    $c_users = $db->twitter_lake;

    // Find
    $user = $c_users->find(array('text' => array('$all' => array(new mongoregex('/teste/i')))));

    $result = Array();
    foreach ($user as $doc) {$result = $doc;}
            return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Será que não é porque você tá substituindo um objeto por outro?

```
$result = Array();
foreach ($user as $doc) {$result[] = $doc;}
        return $result;
```

Comment: GENIAL!!! Valeu amigo